# How can I pass a single FromBody string param to a WEB API method?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

Here is my Web API method signature:

```
[HttpPut]
    public TraceItemNoBreadCrumbs UpdateTraceItem(int traceId, string itemType, string itemId, [FromBody]string notes)
```

I use Postman to test this and in the input body if I just pass:

"My Notes"

and then inspect the incoming param it is correct.
But the front end post needs to pass in like:
data:
{ "notes": "My Notes" }

But when I pass it in, now notes = "notes", not "My Notes" (the first string it sees apparently).

I only have problems with a single string.

In another method I pass in [FromBody] myListObject
like

```
[
    { "prop1": "value", "prop2": "value" }
    { "prop1": "value", "prop2": "value" }
]
```

and it works perfectly.
I just need to fix this for our front end guys.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of taking in a string, I had to model the string inside of an object.
So it looks like:

```
[HttpPut]
    public TraceItemNoBreadCrumbs UpdateTraceItem(int traceId, string itemType, string itemId, [FromBody]TraceItemNote notes)
```

Where TraceItemNote looks like:

```
public class TraceItemNote
{
    public string Notes { get; set; }
}
```

I think because we are sending up JSON objects, they have to have a C# object counterpart.

Answer (score 0):

Since its coming from the body, you don't need to format it as an json object.  just pass "my notes" in the  body by itself.

Comment: This would be a more useful answer if you included the code showing how to do that.